# Why compile a kernel again in Linux?

Tags: linux

I am in beginner level with Linux topics and performances.

I have a question about Linux kernel:
Is there any way to install a kernel without compiling?
Is there any compiled and ready kernel for installation?

Comment: Yes - just buy a dvd

Comment: These days you almost never need to compile a kernel.  Almost every distro comes with a modular kernel.  You can easily enable/disable functions as needed, and compile additional modules for supporting unusual hardware without rebuilding the entire kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Of course. You just have to download (or order a dvd for) one of the popular Linux distributions. Search google for any one of Linux distros like Ubuntu, OpenSuse, Fedora etc. I would suggest Ubuntu, but then its just a matter of personal choice.

Being a beginner compiling the kernel and other software yourself is neither suggested nor practically possible. Later, however, if you find yourself interested enough you may go for compiling a kernel yourself.

Comment: Updated kernels are released from time to time on Ubuntu and Debian, accessible via `aptitude` or synaptic and are typically installed automatically if you have your system updating automatically.  Someone can also compile a kernel and package it in a `.deb` which you can then install with a `dpkg -i` command.

Comment: @ultrasawblade what about fedora? is this common for Linux distributions?

Answer (score -1):

There are binary packages for all distro's of Linux, they are fast-to-install, etc... But a word of warning must be said. First, the kernel config is set ONLY before the compilation, and there's no guarantee that the config used for binary package production will be the best one for your task. Second, the target CPU arch is supported, of course, but not the flavour! Yes, i686 kernel will run on latest i7 cpu for sure, but how fast and how good your hardware utilization will be? But if you have alot of identical setups, you can compile once and generate your own binary package for redistribution and time-saving.